# Can't Travel From Siwa To Alexandria - Install In Progress (Stuck at 28%)

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

I recently bought a pre-owned disc of Assassin's Creed: Origins for the PS4. The game downloaded and installed fine; the console said everything had downloaded (nothing of concern in Downloads).

I played through the beginning of the game with no trouble, took time on side quests and whatever else, really liking the game. Once I got to the point where you confirm you wish to move on from Siwa to Alexandria with Hepzefa, I found myself stuck on the Animus loading screen (the one with the tips, etc.) with a note saying 'Install In Progress, 28% Completed' in the top right corner.

Checked for any download issues and/or console updates once waiting for a good while, and everything was up to par. Googled it, only found the same issue from a few years back (2017, etc. This is 2020), and thought it may be patched by now. Currently reinstalling the entire game, but if that doesn't work, I'm unsure of what else to do other than replace the disc and hope for the best. Any help is appreciated :))

Small Edit: Disc is completely clear of smudges and scratches, thankfully. After deleting and reinstalling, the note now says it is at 24% rather than 28%. Just seems to be going south at this point :')

Comment: It's hard to say with these kind of problems, but what I would try is to check the disc for any damage or smudges, before reinstalling. Other than that, there's not much you (or we) can do, besides contacting Playstation or Ubisoft support. I doubt they will be much help, though.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The disc is completely free of smudges or marks. I double checked and gave it a thorough clean just to be sure before deleting and reinstalling, yet to no avail. I'll try contacting support at this point, and if they're of no help, I'll simply return the disc :)